# Mapbox event listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox

I've added custom buttons to my [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/) map and they shop up correctly. However
when I add a click listener it does not work. I see no error in my console.

The code looks like this:

```
const currentLocationControl = new CustomControl('current-location-control', 'GPS');

this.map.addControl(currentLocationControl, 'top-left');

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    alert('test');
});
```

I execute this code in the `mounted` method from `vue.js`.

The CustomControl:

```
export default class CustomControl {

    constructor(className, text) {
        this.className = className;
        this.text = text;
    }

    onAdd(map){
        this.map = map;
        this.container = document.createElement('div');
        this.container.id = 'test';
        this.container.className = this.className;
        this.container.textContent = this.text;
        return this.container;
    }
    onRemove(){
        this.container.parentNode.removeChild(this.container);
        this.map = undefined;
    }
}
```

When I `console.log(document.getElementById('test'));` I see the expected result in my console (the test div).

[image]

So what could be going on here?

Comment: It's most likely due to the fact that you're building this in javascript so it's not available in the DOM when you're attempting to bind to use. use event delegation off of the closest static parent element instead

Comment: Anyone????!?!?!

Comment: Did you attempt what I told you?

Comment: @ohgodwhy it's within a vue.js component so there is no static parent right? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint at that speciffic line and check if the element is trully there. Also, the event can be bound but the button may appear under the map, so you actually click on themap not the button. Do you have correct z-indexes?

Comment: It would be best if you provide a working Plunker example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might very well be the element does not yet exist, depending on how `map.addControl` works.

Perhaps if you created a method in your `CustomControl` to return the container, and instead of using `document.getElementById` you'd use something like `currentLocationControl.getContainer()`?

Alternatively a `setAction` in your `CustomControl` like

```
setAction(action) {
    this.container.addEventListener('click', action);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that the click event is bind to the correct element, you can bind the event in the Class declaration instead.

Pass a callback for click event to the CustomControl

```
const clickCallback = function(e) {
  alert(test);
};

const currentLocationControl = new CustomControl(
  "current-location-control",
  "GPS",
  clickCallback
);
```

Class declaration:

```
// add clickCallback to constructor
export default class CustomControl {
  constructor(className, text, clickCallback) {
    //...
  }

  onAdd(map) {
    //...
    this.container.onclick = clickCallback;
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jenssen may i know how did you implement it? I'm curious why it's not working